# Kusto - if else with matches regex

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

How do I convert the below Splunk query to Kusto Pls

`| eval result=if(Match(Status,"Success|Passed"), "succeeded","failed")`

I am trying with below in Kusto but it does not work
`| extend result = case(Status matches regex ("Success", "Passed"), "succeeded", "failed")`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
T
| extend result = case(Status contains "Success" or Status contains "Passed", "succeeded", "failed")
```

If "Success" and "Passed" are known to be terms in the source data, you should replace "contains" with "has"; and id they're known to be the entire string, you can use "in()" or "in~()" instead.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datatypes-string-operators